# Is it required to clear docker-logs in AKS / Kubernetes

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, azure-aks

Is it required to clean up docker logs in AKS/Kubernetes? Or even more simple, it is possible to set a maximum log-size in AKS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answers:

- No, you don't have to clean up the docker logs yourself.
- Yes, there is a way to set a maximum log-size but it is not an officially supported method.

There is a config in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` that is responsible for log rotation. See the example below:

```
{
  "live-restore": true,
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts":  {
     "max-size": "50m",
     "max-file": "5"
  }
}
```

You can change those values but it would not be persistent due to the fact that node can be replaced on scale or upgrade operations. There is a workaround however. You can use [knode](https://github.com/juan-lee/knode) in order to change the node configuration:

> knode uses a kubernetes daemonset for node configuration.

More details regarding it can be found in the [linked page](https://github.com/juan-lee/knode).

Please let me know if that helps.